# NoSuchMethodError : The method 'map' was called on null. Plz Provide the Solution

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dictionary, dart

I am trying to parse data from a Rest API inside a Dart/Flutter application.
The `JSON` contains a field called data at the root, which contains a list of Words.
I want to get a `List<ArticalList>` from this JSON giving  `json["data"].map((x) => ArticalList.fromJson(x))`

I already have the following code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

Welcome welcomeFromJson(String str) => Welcome.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(Welcome data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Welcome {
  Welcome({
    required this.code,
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.data,
  });

  final int code;
  final String status;
  final String message;
  final List<ArticalList> data;

  factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
        code: json["code"] ?? 0,
        status: json["status"] ?? '',
        message: json["message"] ?? '',
        data: List<ArticalList>.from(json["data"].map((x) => ArticalList.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "code": code,
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class ArticalList {
  ArticalList({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.detail,
    required this.image,
  });

  int id;
  String title;
  String detail;
  String image;

  factory ArticalList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ArticalList(
        id: json["id"] == null ? 0 : json["id"],
        title: json["title"] == null ? '' : json["title"],
        detail: json["detail"] == null ? '' : json["detail"],
        image: json["image"] ?? 'http://eduteksolutions.in/images/logo.jpeg',
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "title": title == null ? null : title,
        "detail": detail == null ? null : detail,
        "image": image,
      };
}
```

Comment: Can you please inform us with the line that is throwing the error in the code above? Which map function is throwing the error?

Comment: can you provide the json you are trying to parse

Comment: data: List<ArticalList>.from(
**json["data"].map((x) => ArticalList.fromJson(x))),**
);

Comment: https://solutiontrackers.com/TravelApp/api/getArticalList

Comment: data:json["data"]==null?[]: List<ArticalList>.from(
            json["data"].map((x) => ArticalList.fromJson(x))), i check the null but still return Data List is Empty

Answer (score 1):

I think your getting error at

```
data: List<ArticalList>.from(json["data"].map((x) => ArticalList.fromJson(x))),
```

I create a function with null safety which accept map and return object list

```
static List<ArticalList> toListFormMap({
    Map? map,
  }) {
    if (map?.isEmpty ?? true) return [];
    List<ArticalList> items = [];
    map?.forEach((key, data) {
      final ArticalList item = ArticalList.fromJson(data);
      items.add(item);
    });
    return items;
  }
```

and same method which convert map to Map

```
static Map toMapList(List<ArticalList>? items) {
    Map map = {};
    items?.forEach((element) {
      map[element.id] = element.toJson();
    });
    return map;
  }
```

for both case it handle null data error and also convert Object List to Map list and Map list to Object list.
I hope it will be helpful.